# Query Account Data Extension with 2 different keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

Just ran into a little situation, where it seems the query isn't doing what it's supposed to do. I believe it blocks on the joins and then doesn't proceed to the rest. I didn't get an error, but i'll explain in basic what I'm trying to do.

We have our customer database, on Account_Salesforce.
For these customers there are Quotes being created. Now a new feature is that there are also partners of us, who will create Quotes. On the email that is sent through Marketing Cloud, we need the name and address of that partner to show. So I need to get that info. On the Quote itself, I only have an ID, which is also a Business Party, just as our client.

So each Quote should have a customer linked to it. But each Quote doesn't have a partner ID mentionned.

The query looks like this:

```
FROM
SBQQ__Quote__c_Salesforce_1 Q
            LEFT JOIN
                      Account_Salesforce P
                      ON
                            Q.SBQQ__Partner__c = P.Id
            INNER JOIN
                      Account_Salesforce A
                      ON
                            Q.SBQQ__Account__c = A.id
```

There are filters afterwards, but they aren't being performed.
When I put both Joins on INNER I don't get any results (which is normal, since at this moment, in production, there are no Partner ID's yet).

Answer (score 2):

You are starting off the quote. I would approach this the opposite way.

1. get all accounts with their quotes (simple inner join)
2. get all partners with their quotes (simple inner join)
3. make them all a big list (UNION)

In case you work off different base DEs, it's important that you align all fields before the UNION. Since both of your queries are from accounts, it should be a non-issue.

To illustrate:

```
SELECT Id AS ID
FROM

Account_Salesforce a
INNER JOIN
SBQQ__Quote__c_Salesforce_1 q
ON
q.SBQQ__Account__c = a.id

UNION

SELECT Id AS ID
FROM
Account_Salesforce p
INNER JOIN
SBQQ__Quote__c_Salesforce_1 q
ON
q.SBQQ__Partner__c = p.id
```

Comment: Hey Jonas, 
It's a great idea, but there's a catch. 
in Account database we find customers and partners. 
A Quote is made for customers, so we recuperate info from the customer. In Some Quotes, a part from the AccountID for the customer, there is the AccountID for the Partner also referenced. And so I need to get info via AccountID 1 for the customer, and AccountID 2 for the partner.
I'm going to try 2 queries now, one where I get all Quotes for customers. And then an update on that data extension, with possible info from the Partner. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround to bypass this problem.

First Query gives me the info on the customer via the AccountID.
Second Query updates the Data Extension of the first Query, with supplementary info based on the Partner ID matched with AccountID.

Thanks for taking the time to try and solve it Jonas.